# How to get correct shape outline of closed bezier path?

Tags: c#, bezier

I have a directed closed path consisting of (cubic) bezier curves and lines, which represents a pen stroke. When I oversimplify it, it can look something like this:

[image: Directed closed path of bezier curves][image: Two inner cycles in red colour]

In the end, **I need to get the shape outline.** I can recognize inner path cycles (highlighted in red in second picture above), but **can't determine if they represent a hole in the shape or not**. What I've been doing so far is getting a point inside the inner cycle and computing it's winding number (using the [nonzero-rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonzero-rule)) and for the most cases it turns out pretty well.

This is not the case though. No matter in which direction I cast the ray from the little inner cycle, the winding number sum is always (correctly) zero, indicating there's a hole where there should be instinctively none. Two examples:

[image: Ray intersects with a line and bezier curve]
[image: Ray intersects with two bezier curves]

What could probably help is that I can distinguish between both sides of the pen stroke, meaning I can recognize it's start and end (yellow-orange lines) and side paths (green and blue).

[image: All paths are distinguishable]

I can think of some ways this could help. For example crossing the same path (green) twice and not meeting it's counterpart (blue) twice indicates that the point I'm testing lies inside the pen stroke and that I can safely remove the inner cycle inside which it lies (unless it lies inside multiple inner cycles at once, but that doesn't happen in my case). What if I don't meet the blue counterpart, but the yellow line instead - what then?

**Question: Is there any way I could determine that the little cycle is "inside" the pen stroke?** If I'm able to do this, I can get the correct shape outline and later possibly fill the pen stroke.

Just to be clear, when you imagine the pen stroke filled, the should be only one hole, not two, as the nonzero winding rule suggests.

[image: Filled pen stroke]

Thank you.

Comment: for which programming language? Because many of them already have libraries for doing this.

Comment: I'm currently using C# (and would welcome any tip for a library that implements this), but there's a possibility that I'll need to do the same in Objective-C or Swift in the future.

Comment: noted (next time always put the language in question in your post as a tag so that C# people see it). Back to the question: that is not the outline a pen would make, though, it would be a straight up directional offset of the one curve, so: how did you *create* this path? It doesn't match what you describe it as supposedly representing, that would look like this: http://imgur.com/HaQG0S5

Comment: You're right. As I said at the beginning, this was only an oversimplified version. In fact I have exactly what you posted, which complicates the whole thing. I suspected I need to get rid of the loop highlighted in yellow ( http://imgur.com/9ovZADh ) in another way so I didn't post it here to keep it simple.

Comment: no, it doesn't, it *highly* simplifies things because now we're dealing with a straight trace, and the case you're showing is much more complicated. Don't ask questions that you don't want answered, please update your post to ask the question you *do* want answered.